# Android LocationClient mock location not set

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I'm trying to mock locations using the Play Services `LocationClient`. I have:

1. Added the `ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION` permission.
2. Called `setMockMode(true)` on my `LocationClient`
3. Called `setMockLocation(Location)`

However, when I call `getLastLocation()`, I always get `null`. No updates are pushed to the `LocationListener`, and the `null` never changes.

Comment: are you using the same provider while setting the location and fetching the location ?

Comment: In both cases, `flp`, the default fake location provider