# setElapsedRealtimeNanos() call in android mock location provider app

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing an android app, which will receive the current location and display it on the map with a marker and then will keep updating that in regular intervals. I followed the following tutorials:

[Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

[Retrieving the Current Location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

[Receiving Location Updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

I wanted to test my app with mock locations so I followed this tutorial:

[Testing Using Mock Locations](https://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html)

However, because of Google's confusing documentation despite my best attempts the first approach failed. I was having this issue:

[Android LocationClient mock location not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690209/android-locationclient-mock-location-not-set)

Then, I decided to use the mock location provider app and discovered that even though the manifest of the downloaded app has `android:minSdkVersion="7"`, it has a `SendMockLocationService.java` file which has two function calls `elapsedRealtimeNanos()` and `setElapsedRealtimeNanos()` which were added in API Level 17. I need to run this mock location provider app in a device with API Level 8. So, I have changed the line:

```
elapsedTimeNanos = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
```

to

```
elapsedTimeNanos = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()*1000000;
```

It is not clear to me how to change this line:

```
mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(elapsedTimeNanos);
```

How can I change the above-mentioned line so that the mock location provider app becomes compatible with API Level 8?

Comment: You wouldn't change that line because you have already changed the value of elapsedTimeNanos.

Answer (score 2):

I updated [the sample project you referenced](https://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html) to build with gradle this evening, and noticed the same issue with the use of [`setElapsedRealtimeNanos`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#setElapsedRealtimeNanos(long)), introduced in API level 17. The app worked fine on my 4.4 device, but would crash with a NoSuchMethodError on my 4.1 device.

I went digging in the source code of the location class to see exactly what changed for API 17. Here's the corresponding diff:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2eeeec248a38ff33999c83f4b8d5bab7d50e79d2%5E%21/

If you search for usages of the newly-introduced field `mElapsedRealtimeNano`, you'll see that its value is only queried in a single spot (`+` retained to indicate newly-inserted lines):

```
+    public boolean isComplete() {
+        if (mProvider == null) return false;
+        if (!mHasAccuracy) return false;
+        if (mTime == 0) return false;
+        if (mElapsedRealtimeNano == 0) return false;
+        return true;
+    }
```

The newly-introduced notion of a Location being 'complete' is also only used in a single spot:

```
     public void setTestProviderLocation(String provider, Location loc) {
+        if (!loc.isComplete()) {
+            if (mContext.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
+                // for backwards compatibility, allow mock locations that are incomplete
+                Log.w(TAG, "Incomplete Location object", new Throwable());
+                loc.makeComplete();
+            } else {
+                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
+                        "Location object not complete. Missing timestamps or accuracy?");
+            }
+        }
+
         // original setTestProviderLocation code is then executed here
     }
```

Since this validation is missing from the Location class before API 17, the app should work just fine on all API levels >= 7 if you wrap both calls to `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()` in version checks, i.e.

```
elapsedTimeNanos = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
```

should be replaced by

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    elapsedTimeNanos = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
}
```

and

```
mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(elapsedTimeNanos);
```

should be replaced by

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(elapsedTimeNanos);
}
```

within the SendMockLocationService class. Android Studio will complain that `elapsedTimeNanos` may not have been initialized - you can safely initialize it with value 0 to resolve this.

With these changes, the app runs fine on my 4.1 device. Let me know if you have any problems on older versions of Android.

Edit: [repository for my updated version of the Google sample app](https://github.com/stkent/UpdatedMockLocationProvider).